# Configuring FTP on EC2 micro Linux Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

i have some question i want to configure FTP on my EC2 instance.

1.is ec2 micro linux instance install vsftpd by default or we have to install it manually?

2.is ec2-user has administrative right? (when i try to execute yum install command it refuse and say you dont have administrative right).

kindly help me in this regard. thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not installed, install it via yum.
2. Use `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the accepted answer:

The default user 'ec2-user' is not root (in fact EC2 instances will not allow you to login as as root). Once logged in as 'ec2-user' issue `sudo su -` to gain root.

`yum install vsftpd` should then install vsftpd.